# Properly positioning nested flexbox divs

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am trying to achieve a structure with flexboxes that looks like this:

[image: like this]

But as of now what I have achieved looks like this:

[image: like this]

That is, I can't get the text in the nested div to be displayed below the image with left-alignment;

Here's the relevant HTML :

```
    <div class='page'>
              /*Some more divs*/


            <div class='section feature-1 ' >
              <img src='image1.jpg' class='divToShowHide' height="30%" 
               width="50%"/>

                <div class='section feature-1 feature-1-content'>
                <h2>TEXT HERE !
                </h2></div>
            </div>


          /*More similar divs here*/

    </div>
```

And here's the relevant CSS:

```
.page {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}


.section {
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
.feature-1 {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  background-color: #F5CF8E;
  align-items: flex-start;
  justify-content: flex-start;


}
.feature-1-content{
  align-items: center;

}

.feature-1 img{

  padding: 5px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

How can I get the Image and the text of the feature-1 div to be positioned as I want them to ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `flex-direction: row` in `.feature-1` to `flex-direction: column` and they will stack vertically.

Answer (score 0):

You need to also add `flex-wrap: wrap` to your nested flex container.

If the parent of the image and text elements isn't set to `wrap`, then child elements will appear in one row.